# When do I need to put "on" after "improve"?

Tags: prepositions

When do I need to put "on" after "improve"? I have seen things like

> "He has **improved his** conversational skills this semester a lot."

and I have also seen things like

> "He has **improved on his** previous results in this subject's tests."

So, I am at loss here as to when "on" is needed in such cases and when it's not.

Comment: In the given cases, both are acceptable. HMB while I think of some where it doesn't work.

Comment: @Blacksilver - What do you mean by "HMB"?

Comment: **H**old **M**y **B**eer.

Comment: @Blacksilver - Does that mean that it's rather hard for you to think of an example where it doesn't work (which means that there probably aren't any such cases), or does it mean that you would rather not bother to think of an example where it doesn't work?

Comment: Man, this deserves it's own question. It means it's hard... I geuss? It really depends on context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as in your examples, you would use

> He has **improved on** his personal best time over the past year.
>   Ha has **improved upon** his personal best over the past year.

when you are talking about a specific *level* of improvement, whereas

> He has **improved** his running times over the past year.

describes a general amount of improvement.

Answer (score 0):

"Improved X" means "made X better".

"Improved on X" means "got something better than X".

There can be some overlap. For example, if I *improve on* my personal best time, it means that I get a time better than my previous best time which is the same as *improving* my best time.  On the other hand, if I improve on *your* best time, I get a better time but it doesn't improve your best time.